# How can I write CSS that only applies to specific browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a line of CSS that acts differently in IE than it does for every other browsers. I want this line to look like this in all browsers:

```
.header-ie .wrapper-ie:after { 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:-33px; 
    width:100%; 
    height:34px; 
    content:""; 
    left:0; 
    background:url(../shadow-bg.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size:100% auto; 
    pointer-events:none
}
```

I want it to look like this in IE (9 or lower):

```
.header-ie .wrapper-ie:after{ 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:-250px; 
    width:100%; 
    height:34px; 
    content:""; 
    left:0; 
    background-size:100% auto; 
    pointer-events:none
}
```

How can I accomplish this in my style sheet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser-specific+css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change 1 or 2 things, you can use per-propery hack:

From: http://codemug.com/html/css-hacks-for-ie6ie7ie8ie9-and-ie10/

```
#hack{
color:red; /* All browsers */
color:red !important;/* All browsers but IE6 */
_color:red; /* Only works in IE6 */
*color:red; /* IE6, IE7 */
+color:red;/* Only works in IE7*/
*+color:red; /* Only works in IE7 */
color:red\9; /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 */
color:red\0; /* IE8, IE9 */
color:red\9\0;/*Only works in IE9*/
}
```

So you'll end up with

```
.header-ie .wrapper-ie:after { 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:-33px;
    bottom:-250px\9; 
    width:100%; 
    height:34px; 
    content:""; 
    left:0; 
    background:url(../shadow-bg.png) no-repeat center;
    background:none\9;
    background-size:100% auto;
    pointer-events:none
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML page, you can implement a conditional CSS file.   Call this *after* you have called you other stylesheet(s).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/site.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/ie-legacy.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You may need to decorate the classes attributes in the ie-legacy.css with an !important.

**NOTE:** IE9 (and lower) will no longer receive security or feature updates from Microsoft after January 12, 2016.